# Does the MODIStsp package computes the QA's and eventually corrects the bad quality pixels?

Tags: r, modis, pixel, data-quality

I am using R's MODIStsp package for downloading MOD11A2 time series products.

While executing the command it was written that QA's were computed. Several files were created, LST_Day_1km, QC_Day, QAday_LST_err, QAday_mand, QAday_qual.

My question is, in which folder the 'corrected' images are? Or the package simply computes the QA's and I have to use the other package in order to produce images which contain pixels with the best quality?

Answer (score 1):

The package computes the QA's but it does not produce new images which contain only the pixels with the best quality.